# jsp - javascript - click event For loop id elements to update a record in database

Tags: javascript, jsp

I try to set click event for each id element (div tag) to change background div and update a record showed on this div but not working....All of records in table change status Readed=True but I want to change only the record when i clicked.How can i solve that?

index.jsp

```
  String query2 = "select * from Notifications where UserId=1 and Readed='False' and DeleteStatus='False'";
                                        PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query2);
                                        ResultSet rs10 = pstmt2.executeQuery();
                                        while (rs10.next()) {
                                    %>

                                    <div class="notifbox" >
                                        <div class=" notif unread" id="<%=rs10.getInt("IdNotice")%>">

                                            <div class="messageblock">
                                                <div class="message" style="width: 300px"><%=rs10.getString("Content")%>
                                                    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<a href="#" class='<%=rs10.getInt("IdNotice")%>' style="color: red;font-weight: bold">X</a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <%

                                        }

                                    %>
```

javascript

```
                            $(document).ready(function() {

            <%    String query22 = "select * from Notifications where UserId=1 and Readed='False' and DeleteStatus='False'";
                PreparedStatement pstmt22 = conn.prepareStatement(query22);
                ResultSet rs22 = pstmt22.executeQuery();
                while (rs22.next()) {
            %>
                                $('#<%=rs22.getInt("IdNotice")%>').click(function() {
                                    $('#<%=rs22.getInt("IdNotice")%>').css('background-color', '#FFF');

            <%     String query8 = "UPDATE Notifications SET Readed='True' where  IdNotice=?";

                PreparedStatement pstmt8 = conn.prepareStatement(query8);
                pstmt8.setInt(1, rs22.getInt("IdNotice"));

                pstmt8.executeUpdate();

            %>
                               });


            <%  }%>
```

Update Javascript

```
   <%    String query22 = "select * from Notifications where (SellAccount=? or AgentAccount=?) and Readed='False' and DeleteStatus='False'";
                PreparedStatement pstmt22 = conn.prepareStatement(query22);
                pstmt22.setString(1, "nguyenson1");
                pstmt22.setString(2, "nguyenson1");
                ResultSet rs22 = pstmt22.executeQuery();
                while (rs22.next()) {
            %>
                            $('#<%=rs22.getInt("IdNotice")%>').on('click', function() {
                            
                                $('#<%=rs22.getInt("IdNotice")%>').css('background-color', '#FFF');

                                window.location.href = "updateRead?seller=nguyenson1&agent=nguyenson1&idNotice=<%=rs22.getInt("IdNotice")%>";
```

});
<%  }%>

[index.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9MCX.png)

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXj6P.png)

Comment: Please Help me!!! my code show in 2 attached photos .So sorry! my english is not good!!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I don't see where you are setting an ``onClick`` handler on your ``div``. It just looks like as soon as the page loads your JS sets everything to read. Also, you don't need to post images of code too; just the code you copied is fine.

Comment: Hi  @rmlockerd in this case ,How can i set onClick=?   ,u can type more clearly...thank you very very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing js and jsp code. Try to separate it. Onclick javascript handler should do to two things:

- change background color
- make a request to backend side with id of the notification

Change of notification to DB should be done on server side.

Comment: Hi @Thinh Tran,Thank for help!!! ,i just have update code but i have another problem that is when i call servlet ,i have to reload another page then servlet just response but i want to call servlet then keep same page and servlet still response....

Comment: Since you are using jQuery. You can simply make an ajax call.